# what is difference between using Instance and using getsupportFragmentmanager().findFragmentid();

Tags: android

I want to use Method (declared in Fragment) in Activity.
(I want to control Fragment by using Activity )

when I used this code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
        NumList NumList = new NumList();
        GetNumber GetNumber = new GetNumber();
        CheckNum CheckNum = new CheckNum();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.e("액티비티","온크리에이트");

        FragmentTransaction Transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Transaction2.add(R.id.frame,CheckNum);
        Transaction2.add(R.id.frame,NumList);
        Transaction2.add(R.id.frame,GetNumber);
        Transaction2.commit();

        Fragment();

        SetNum();


    }

    public void SetNum() {

                Log.e("아니저한테왜그러세요대체에에에","GG");
        final Button MyButton = findViewById(R.id.MyButton);
        MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                GetNumber getNumber = (GetNumber) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);

                GetNumber.Test();   //GetNumber is first Fragment.

            }
        });
    }}
```

But When I used this code,,,

```
public void SetNum() {

                Log.e("아니저한테왜그러세요대체에에에","GG");
        final Button MyButton = findViewById(R.id.MyButton);
        MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NumList numList = (NumList)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
                numList.TestBtn();
            }
        });
    }
```

<java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.lottoooo.GetNumber cannot be cast to com.example.lottoooo.NumList> is occured....

To solve this proble, I Changed
NumList numList = (NumList)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
to
NumList.TestBtn();  (I used Instance already declared) so I can solve problem....

what is the difference using Instance and using getsupportFragmentmanager().findFragmentid();  ?

(I apologize for my terrible English level...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `getsupportFragmentmanager().findFragmentid()` return the last fragment you add to `FragmentTransaction` it means with your code it always return `GetNumber` fragment.

You already store instances of `fragment` in `Activity` (NumList, GetNumber ...), basically, it's the same instance when you get by `getsupportFragmentmanager()`. But it's not recommended, for example when you call any method by instance (instead of finding from fragment manager) sometimes it can execute before `FragmentTransaction` complete, it can throw an exception. You can try this and no need store instance inside `Activity`

```
    FragmentTransaction Transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Transaction2.add(R.id.frame,CheckNum(), "CheckNum");
    Transaction2.add(R.id.frame,NumList(), "NumList");
    Transaction2.add(R.id.frame,GetNumber(), "GetNumber");
    Transaction2.commit();
```

```
    MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NumList numList = (NumList)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("NumList");
            numList.TestBtn();
        }
    });
```